# Is this a typo in the "SQL Anti-Patterns" book?

Tags: sql, database-design, tree, nested-sets, anti-patterns

Relevant section:

> **Nested Sets.**
>
> The Nested Sets solution stores information with each node that
>   pertains to the set of its descendants, rather than the node's
>   immediate parent. This information can be represented by encoding each
>   node in the tree with two numbers, which you can call `nsleft` and
>   `nsright`.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE Comments ( 
>    comment_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
>    nsleft       INTEGER NOT NULL,
>    nsright      INTEGER NOT NULL,
>    bug_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>    author       BIGINT UNISGNED NOT NULL,
>    comment_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
>    comment      TEXT NOT NULL,
>    FOREIGN KEY  (bug_id) REFERENCES Bugs (bud_id),
>    FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES Accounts(account_id)
> );
> ```
>
> Each node is given `nsleft` and `nsright` numbers in the following way:
>   the `nsleft` number is less than the numbers of all the node's
>   children, whereas the right number is greater than the numbers of all
>   the node's children. These numbers have no relation to the
>   `comment_id` values.

(pg. 32 of SQL Anti-Patterns)

Shouldn't it say

> the `nsleft` number is less than the numbers of all the node's
>   ***descendants***, whereas the right number is greater than the numbers of
>   all the node's ***descendants***.

or is my understanding of this concept flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it isn't a typo, but you're also correct that it applies to the descendants, so you understand the situation — you just haven't quite thought it all the way through.

Suppose the tree has 3 levels.  For each node at the lowest, leaf level, there are no children.  At the intermediate level, each node has an `nsleft` smaller than the smallest `nsleft` of any of its children (the leaf nodes) and an `nsright` larger than the largest `nsright` of any of its children.  Similarly, at the top level, the single root node has an `nsleft` smaller than the smallest `nsleft` of any of its direct children, and an `nsright` larger than the largest `nsright` of any of its direct children.  But, by induction, that means that the root node's `nsleft` node is smaller than the smallest `nsleft` of any of its descendents, and its `nsright` node is larger than largest `nsright` of any of its descendents.

So, the statement is accurate as written, but your inference is also correct.